# Multirow multicolumn table problem

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I am trying to make a table like this one [image: Multirow multicolumn table with vertical text]

But having problems with the vertical text. Can anyone please help me to create the table? Thank you in advance.

My attempt

```
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

    \begin{supertabular}{| c | c | p{4cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Title}} & \textbf{Title} & 
\textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title}\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}[-3cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{R1}}
 & A Lot of Text   & really a lot of text really a lot of text 
 really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text 
 really a lot of text really a lot of text &  &  \\
\cline{2-5}

& A Lot of Text   & really a lot of text really a lot of text 
really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text 
really a lot of text really a lot of text & & \\


\hline

\multirow{4}{*}[-1 cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{R1}}
 & A Lot of Text   & really a lot of text really a lot of text 
 really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text 
 really a lot of text really a lot of text &  &  \\
\hline
\end{supertabular}
```

Update: I am able to create the table (not exactly but it will work for me). Right now my concern is to make it compatible with the multipage table.

Comment: Could you please post what you tried (complete code)?

Comment: I think I am able to solve the problem. Right now my concern is to make it compatible with multipage

Comment: The problem  is that a  \multirow  cannot break across pages.